# C++ pass parent pointer to a parent class constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am currently developing a game in C++. Now I am a beginner in C++ and am just trying to get used to the concept of multiple inheritance. My game has a player class. That player class inherits from Positionable(gives the player x and y coords) and Moveable(allows the player to move around). The problem is that Moveable has to know the player coords to move him around adequately. Here's basic pseudo(ish) code of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
class Movable
{

private:
    Positionable *positionable;

public:
    Movable(Positionable *positionable)
        : positionable(positionable)
    { }

    void Translate(float x, float y)
    {
        positionable->setX(positionable->getX() + x);
        positionable->setY(positionable->getY() + y);
    }
}

class Positionable
{
private: 
    float x, y;
public:
    Positionable(float x, float y)
        : x(x),
        y(y)

    float getX() { return this->x; }
    float getY() { return this->y; }
    float setX(float val) { this->x = val; }
    float setY(float val) { this->y = val; }
}

class Player : public Positionable, public Movable
{
    Player(float x, float y)
        : Positionable(x, y)
        : Movable((Positionable) this)
    { }
}

...

Player player;
player.Translate(50, 50)
```

My question is is there a better way to pass `Positionable` to the constuctor of Movable, because if `Moveable` depended on 3 classes I would have to write something like `Movable((FirstClass) this, (SecondClass) this, (ThirdClass) this)`. This looks bad. Is there some way I can solve this problem better?

Comment: The 'I' prefix indicates that you meant to have interfaces, but you've actually created concrete classes without any polymorphic behaviors (no virtual functions). An advice is to skip the 'I' to not confuse yourself or others.

Comment: Why don't you make sure IMovable inherit from IPositionable, because it needs the position in order to move and make Player inherit from  IMovable? Then in constructor let Player call IMovable and that inturn call IPositionable with the x,y values.
Wouldn't this solve your problem?

Comment: You don't have to cast (moreover you cast in the wrong type: missing `*`).

Comment: I didn't compile the code, it was just an example so you can get an idea of what I want to achieve. I will take your advice into account

Comment: @BandiKishore I would upvote that answer. Any solution avoiding multiple inheritance is almost by definition avoiding more head ache in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BandiKishore suggested in the comments, a better way is to inherit `Movable` from `Positionable` (and inherit `Player` from `Movable` only). `Movable` needs access to coordinates to do its moving work, and the name `Movable` suggests that it should move itself (`this`), not some other object (in which case it would be `Mover` or `MovingHelper` or smth. like that), so inheritance is more logical than delegation.

`Player` would have to invoke only one base constructor:

```
class Movable : public Positionable
{
public:
    Movable(float x, float y) : Positionable(x, y)
    { }
}

class Player : public Movable
{
    Player(float x, float y) : Movable(x, y)
    { }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would turn your IPositionable class into a struct if you are only using it to hold/access X and Y values.

If you haven't used structs before, here is a brief overview: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/

Now as far as your IMoveable class, I would put an IPositionable member in the class as you did but intialize it in your IMoveable contstructor. Here is a really rough example of what I mean:

```
    class IMovable
    {

     private:
        IPositionable *positionable;

     public:
        IMovable(int x, int y)
        { 
            positionable->setX(x);
            positionable->setY(y);
        }

        void Translate(float x, float y)
        {
            positionable->setX(positionable->getX() + x);
            positionable->setY(positionable->getY() + y);
        }
    }
```

then you'll have:

```
    class Player
    {
        private IMoveable moveable;
        Player(float x, float y)
            : moveable(x, y)
        { }
    }

    ...

    Player player(100, 100);
    player.Translate(50, 50);
```

This is merely building from your code example. I did not run this example locally.

Basically, you do not need to use multiple inheritance to accomplish this task. I would suggest not even using inheritance for this task as it is not needed and you should try not to use inheritance if you are not required to! It is something to be very cautious about.